# Java 8: How BiFunction works while using andThen() and apply() methods

Tags: java, builder, functional-interface

Currently `BiFunction` interface has two methods `andThen()` and `apply()`. I found different examples in web, but the below example is something I can't figure out - 'How the chaining of these methods works'

**Example 1:**

```
BiFunction<String, String,String> bi = (x, y) -> {
                    return x + y;
                    };

Function<String,String> f = x-> x+" spinner";

System.out.println(bi.andThen(f).apply("hello", " world"));
```

After reading following link '[Default andThen() method in BiFunction interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074620/default-andthen-method-in-bifunction-interface)', I took below lines

> Assume we had two functions f and g , function f doing some logic and function g doing some other type of logic so when you compose f.andThen(g) that essentially means g(f(x)) i.e. we first apply the function given as argument f(x) and then apply the function g to the result.

and concluded that `bi.apply("hello", " world"))` happens first and then the `result` is
passed on to `bi.andThen(f(result))` and this gives final output `hello world spinner`.

I understood to some extent, but not completely satisfied. I had to ask this because in the past I have used builder pattern and it is something like the below,

```
BankAccount account = new BankAccount.Builder("bank_account")
                                 .withOwner("account_owner")
                                 .atBranch("branch_name")
                                 .openingBalance(balance)
                                 .build();
```

Here, the method calling happens in sequence, first the `Builder` (static) class gets initialised, then `withOwner` assigns owner name and returns builder, and then branch name is assigned and returns builder,
next opening balance is given and returns builder, and finally build will return `BankAccount` instance. Please see the `BankAccount` class.

```
public class BankAccount {

    public static class Builder {

        private long accountNumber; 
        private String owner;
        private String branch;
        private double balance;

        public Builder(long accountNumber) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }

        public Builder withOwner(String owner){
            this.owner = owner;
            return this; 
        }

        public Builder atBranch(String branch){
            this.branch = branch;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder openingBalance(double balance){
            this.balance = balance;
            return this;
        }



        public BankAccount build(){
            //Here we create the actual bank account object, which is always in a fully initialised state when it's returned.

            BankAccount account = new BankAccount();  //Since the builder is in the BankAccount class, we can invoke its private constructor.
            account.accountNumber = this.accountNumber;
            account.owner = this.owner;
            account.branch = this.branch;
            account.balance = this.balance;

            return account;
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the methods are called in sequence and the output of methods -`withOwner`, `atBranch`, `openingBalance`, is `Builder` instance in the chain. and for me this is called chaining of methods, because the output of each method in sequence is used for later and this is very clear. But, my ask is - how the chaining of methods of the above example 1 `(BiFunction and its methods chaining)` works **internally**.

Comment: I doubt the documentation of `andThen` reads *chaining* anywhere. Besides which I don't see a point in comparing a `Builder` pattern with a composed function. What brings in the confusion here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the default implementation:

```
default <V> BiFunction<T, U, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t, U u) -> after.apply(apply(t, u));
}
```

As you can see, first they call the `apply` method of the `BiFunction` (i.e. they evaluate `apply(t, u)`), and the result of that method is passed to the `Function`'s `apply` method (`after.apply(...)`).

I'm not sure why you feel `andThen` doesn't call the methods in sequence. After all `bi.andThen(f)` creates a `BiFunction` that first calls `bi`'s `apply` method and then calls `f`'s `apply` method (just as the name `andThen` implies).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple *function composition*, meaning if we were to give the resulting function a name:

```
BiFunction<String, String, String> composed = bi.andThen(f);
```

Then a simple definition would be:

```
composed(x,y) = f(bi(x,y))
```

So `BiFunction.andThen` returns a `BiFunction` that will apply the current (`bi`) function's logic to compute a result that's then passed to another function (`f`), applying its logic to return the final output.

Answer (score 0):

The `andThen` method differs from the `Builder` pattern in several ways:

`andThen` returns a new function that is the composition of two other functions, whereas each method of the builder returns itself, just to allow the chaining of method calls, thus making the code more compact, but you can also write:

```
BankAccount.Builder builder = new BankAccount.Builder("bank_account");
builder.withOwner("account_owner");
builder.atBranch("branch_name");
builder.openingBalance(balance);
BankAccount account = builder.build();
```

Also, with the `andThen` method, everything is immutable, whereas the builder is inherently mutable (although the built object is often itself immutable).